# React Router setup for 'unlimited' params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement the React Router in such a way that it supports a route like this:

```
/myPages/:pageName1/:pageName2/:pageName3/...
```

The idea is that, even though the page being rendered is only the last page, the pages are nested, and the depth is not something that is pre-determined. The component that renders the actual page needs to know the names of parent pages.

To clarify, the idea is that the page data in the backend are in a tree structure in such a way that, in the above example, page1 is the root page, page 2 is a child of page1, page 3 is a child of page2, etc. In addition, one page can have multiple children. The last child name (so pageName3 in the example) is what is being used to query the database and get all the content required to render the full page. The parent names are required to render navigation-related subcomponent. I should also mention that just having `/myPages/:pageName3` and getting all parent names from the backend is not really an option. I *could* fetch that information from the backend, but the URL presented to the user still needs to have that structure.

I am hoping that there's a way to get this type of information as an array, but I am having a hard time finding an example like this on the web.

Comment: Can you show an example of the kind of content you are trying to render and why you would need this?  Your description is relatively vague, and "nested pages" with "unlimited depth" don't exactly make sense.  at some point, that kind of nesting would result in a screen area that would be too small to render anything in anyway...

Comment: Yes, of course. please see above for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/d28d46dce08a5756a085f7e5eebb5169ea59e40b/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#from-string

states:

> A pathname to redirect from. Any valid URL path that path-to-regexp@^1.7.0 understands.

maybe you can combine 
`<Redirect from='/users/:id' to='/users/profile/:id'/>`

with

`var re = pathToRegexp('/:foo+', keys)`
(taken from https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#one-or-more)

then you'll end up with
`<Redirect from='/:pageName+/:id' to='/:id'/>`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.